# What is the link between Baud rate for embedded C pointers

Tags: c, embedded, baud-rate

I am reading manuals regarding controlling a device with C,and in general its just playing with addresses; however when we are connected through UART we have the BAUDRATE present.

So how putting a value into some address have to do with baud-rate?

Is it necessary in embedded programming?

Comment: I think you're confusing multiple issues and the end result is I can't even make sense of your question. Pointers and baud rate have nothing to relate them. Do you mean "a pointer in a structure" which you're not showing? Code to illustrate the issue would help a lot.

Comment: @tadman I doubt he has code - he says he has just been reading manuals.  Presumably the manuals for the micro-controller or whatever he is using.  Such manuals are of course not embedded system tutorials and assume prior knowledge and expertise.  It seems the issue is a lack of knowledge of the concept of memory-mapped I/O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those addresses are *not memory*.  They are *memory-mapped I/O* registers.

The address for your UART's baud rate divisor register is a hardware register.  The value in hardware registers directly control the hardware.  The value written to baud rate divisor register is typically a counter reload value, and one bit period is the time it takes to count up-to (or down from) the value in the divisor given a specific peripheral clock source.  So for exaample if the UART peripheral clock were say 12MHz, and you wanted a baud rate of 19200, you would set the divisor register to 12x10<sup>6</sup>/19200 = 625.

Although you can read and write hardware registers as if they were memory, they do not necessarily behave like memory.  Some registers may be read-only, others write only, and some writing may have a different effect than reading, such that if you write a value, the value read back will not be what was written.  This often works at the bit level, so that each bit in a register may exhibit different behaviour.

For example on many UART implementations the register to which your write data to be sent, is the same address you read for received data - however they are not the same register, but rather a read-only register and a write-only register mapped to the same address.

It is not specifically an embedded programming thing, but rather an I/O hardware thing; it is simply that outside of embedded systems you are not typically writing directly to the hardware unless you happen to be writing a kernel device driver, where you will encounter the same thing.

As well as the device manuals which necessarily assume existing knowledge and expertise, perhaps you should consult a more general reference.  Now you know the key term: *"memory-mapped I/O"* or *MMIO*, you are in a better position to Google it.  Examples:

- http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch14s03.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O